# How to exclude a month from my time-series data?

Tags: r, time-series

I have time series data "workdata". I am trying to exclude "7" month from my data. I have already tried:

```
workdata[as.integer(format(workdata$date, "%m")) != 7, ]
```

It works, but when i use command:

```
view(workdata)
```

The workdata shows all the months. It is not deleting the July month.

What is wrong with my script?

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried assigning the result back to your frame?

```r
workdata = workdata[as.integer(format(workdata$date, "%m")) != 7, ]
```

Comment: Just to make sure: most of the functions you will use do not cause side effects (i.e, change your dataframe inplace), so you should reassign the result back to your dataframe